# Alternative (cloud) deployment options for a console application

Tags: java, cloud, console-application

I have a fairly large console application written in Java 7 that manages a fair amount of our order processing.

The application consumes a number of web services for orders, interfaces with a database and inserts data into an ERP system. The requirements of the application specified no user interaction, so Java EE was not considered during project planning.

That being said, one of the initiatives this year is to look to the cloud for ways to eliminate cost and improve efficiency. As such I am trying to determine if a console based application can be deployed to a cloud service such as OpenShift or Heroku with little to no changes.

So, the question is: **Can a Java console application be deployed to a cloud service or application server with little to no changes?**

--Edit--

As mentioned below it is possible, but how? What resources should I look at to deploy a jar console application to an application server and have it run successfully?

Comment: What do you mean by deployed to a cloud service? If your console application is normally run by the end-users on their own machines, then no, it can't; you'd have to create some interface between the end-users and the application running in your cloud instance. Cloud services are generally very much like any other hosted server environment, with a few nuances. Don't let buzzwords cloud your vision :)

Comment: @Adrian Deployment right now is on my development machine - What I'm trying to determine is if a cloud service, such as Heroku or OpenShift, which are used to host Java EE applications running on an AS or some other web container, can be manipulated to running a jar. Does that make sense?

Comment: As far as the application itself - it can live anywhere - its only requirement is that we have access to the console to stop/start or restart the application as required - The downside is that we cannot deploy it as a service as 1. Our IT dept doesn't want it on our servers and 2. It further embeds it to my machine, which is something we want to eliminate.

Comment: They can run the JAR, yes. But if your console application is intended to be operated by a user, the only way they can use it is to log in to your cloud system via shell and execute the JAR via command line.

Comment: @Adrian Excellent, can you add it as an answer and possibly point me to some reading material so I can see if it will fit our requirements?

Answer (score 1):

yes it can be , atleast I tried the same with Jelastic and it worked quite well.
Please check the http://jelastic.com/docs/standalone-application for more details